# Why perl is faster than d language?

Tags: performance, perl

Simply program hello world program (bellow you have the code of D and of perl) is faster in perl (interpreted language) than in D (compiled lang). Why?

```
//D language (ldc compiler)

import tango.io.Stdout;
void main()
{
    int i=0;
    while (i<1000)
    {
     Stdout("Hola Món").newline;
     i = i+1;
    }
}
```

and

```
my $i = 0;
while ($i<1000)
{
    print "Hola Món\n";
    $i = $i+1;
}
```

and the time is:

```
time perl hello.pm 

real    0m0.047s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.012s

time ./hola
real    0m0.070s
user    0m0.044s
sys 0m0.012s
```

Why?

Comment: This question is better suited to Stack Overflow, I think, so I'm flagging it. But just in case - that code is 99% syscalls (printf), and perl probably optimizes the surrounding loop really well. I'd say try something more complex that doesn't rely so heavily on a single syscall.

Comment: @Eduardo that is the answer. Put it as an answer for upvotes, etc.

Comment: Note that in Perl the source code is compiled at run time and therefore can execute more quickly than one would expect from a strictly interpreted language.

Comment: Never try to make any kind of performance comparisons with something as trivial as a Hello World program. The results will never be meaningful. I recall seeing something similar many years ago "proving" that Forth is faster than pure assembly language.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that code is 99% syscalls (printf), and perl probably optimizes the surrounding loop really well. I'd say try something more complex that doesn't rely so heavily on a single syscall.

Also, it makes sense for perl to be optimized for quick startup given its partial focus on complementing/replacing the Unix toolbox (sed, awk). So I would guess it's not surprising it performs better than other dynamic languages for compact programs like this one.

Comment: As Eduardo said, D is not optimized very well, particularly with your compiler. "LDC already compiles a lot of D code, but should still be considered _*beta*_ quality." (taken from http://www.dsource.org/projects/ldc (emphasis added)). My guess is that same D code in C (using stdio.h, of course) and compiled with optimization would perform only marginally better than the perl due to the syscalls as Eduardo said.

Comment: To identify a potential culprit, I wouldn't be surprised if the use of the `newline` language construct is part of the issue; D might be doing something similar to what Java does, and treating concatenation of `a` and `b` as `new StringBuffer("a").append("b").toString()` (whereas the one in Perl is just throwing a bunch of bytes out the door, as the `\n` is resolved at compile-time).

Answer (score 2):

Perl uses an output buffer so  the code is not doing the same thing and your Perl program needs less syscalls.
Try `$| = 1;` in Perl to disable the output buffer, or use a stringbuilder in D to get more compareable results.

Additionally newline in D looks like a runtime function call that could be avoided. To get the maximum performance in D you could try to use static (compile time) functions and build the whole string at compile time.